# .htaccess RewriteEngine rules separation

Tags: .htaccess

Hello **Stackoverflow** community, I am currently writing my .htaccess file and wondering, which is the best way to combine Rewrite Engine rules.

For example, my .htaccess file right now consists of the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I want to add the Removing Extension code (for .html):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

As well as the index.html removable code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

***Which is the appropriate order to type them and how should the final .htaccess file code look like?***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.html [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /$1/index.html [END]

RewriteRule ^/?(.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

You may have to tweek things a little, your question is vague in a few points.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I know little about `cPanel`, that is some third party thing I never used myself. The question is about the configuration of an apache http server. For that an excellent documentation is offered which explains in detail which directives can be used where in the configuration. I'd say it makes much more sense to start reading that documentation instead of trying around with snippets and recommendations you find somewhere in the internet.